# Wrap equations in box in Shiny Dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm having an issue in `shinydashboard` where equations that I'm writing are not wrapping when placed in a `box`. The equations are extending beyond the limits of the `box`. MWE:

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)

# UI
ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),

    dashboardSidebar(),

    dashboardBody(
        fluidRow(
            column(width = 6,
                   box("Long Equation", width = 12,

                       h3(withMathJax("$$ \\alpha  + \\beta + \\gamma + \\delta + \\alpha  + \\beta + \\gamma + \\delta + \\alpha  + \\beta + \\gamma + \\delta + $$")))

                       )  
        )
    )
)

# Server
server <- function(input, output) {

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This example yields:

[image]

I have had this same problem with dataframes in `boxes` as well, but can't find any answers online. Does anyone have a solution for ensuring that `box` contents don't extend beyond the boundary of the `box`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the MathJax config to use:

```
  dashboardBody(
    tags$head(tags$script(type = "text/x-mathjax-config", 
                          'MathJax.Hub.Config({
  "HTML-CSS": { linebreaks: { automatic: true } },
         SVG: { linebreaks: { automatic: true } }
});')),
    fluidRow(......
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work when the `box` is within a `tabItem`. I have posted a separate question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57610899/equation-wrapping-with-shiny-dashboard. I would be very grateful if you would take a look at the new question.

Comment: @bjorn2bewild Hmm strange. Sorry, I tried but I didn't manage.

Comment: Odd. Thank you for looking into it.