# Equation wrapping with Shiny Dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I just posted a question regarding equation wrapping with `shinydashboard` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57609922/wrap-equations-in-box-in-shiny-dashboard). The answer presented worked, but my actual example is more complicated and includes `tabItems`. Unfortunately, including the MathJax config at the beginning of the `dashboardBody` does not wrap the equation when the `box` is in a `tabItem`. MWE:

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)

# UI
ui <- dashboardPage(

    dashboardHeader(),

    dashboardSidebar(
        menuItem( "TEST", tabName = "test", selected = T)
    ),

    dashboardBody(
        tags$head(tags$script(type = "text/x-mathjax-config", 'MathJax.Hub.Config({
                              "HTML-CSS": { linebreaks: { automatic: true } },
                                     SVG: { linebreaks: { automatic: true } }
                              });')),

        tabItems(


            tabItem(tabName = "test",



                    fluidRow(


                        column(width = 6,
                               box("Long Equation", width = 12,

                                   h3(withMathJax("$$ \\alpha  + \\beta + \\gamma + \\delta + \\alpha  + \\beta + \\gamma + \\delta + \\alpha  + \\beta + \\gamma + \\delta + $$")))

                        )  
                    )


                    )
        )


    )
)

# Server
server <- function(input, output) {

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The preceding code yields:

[image]

I have tried placing the MathJax config at the beginning of `tabItems` and `tabItem` to no avail. Can anyone explain where to place the MathJax config? A brief explanation of MathJax config more generally would be quite helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You set the width of the column to 6 (`width=6`), but for the box you have a width of 12 (`width=12`). If you fix that it works
[image]

In addition, if you need to keep the column of that width, you can set `style = 'overflow-x: scroll` to add a scrolling bar. 
[image]

Comment: - is there a way you can help with this problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73130780/how-to-bring-4-boxes-into-one-row-with-golem-shiny-app